# redefining functions in clojure

Tags: clojure

I would like to redefine some functions in my program on startup according to some metadata on those functions.

I am new to clojure so I would like what is the idiomatic way to accomplish this.

What I would like to do is use a cache (like memcache) to cache results of some functions (database results). In similar way like memoize or contrib core.cache, but i would like to redefine original functions transparently to the rest of the program, according to metadata which defines the caching policy.

Java libraries usually use annotations and code generation to accomplish this. But I am wandering what is idiomatic clojure way of accomplishing this?

I have explored a few options on the internet but they don't seem too satisfactory. 
Binding is not what I want because it only works on the current thread.
Other options seems to be using some internal java functions which I would like to avoid, or
binding *ns* and rerefining functions with eval.

I understand that i can list the potential functions in one namespace with (keys (ns-publics 'foo)), but have not explored yet how to list non public functions and how to list available namespaces (currently loaded?) - maybe there is namespace loading hook i can use?

EDIT:
This is a small example of what I have in mind. Wrap is a function that would perform caching according to origs metadata. Caching and metadata are absent from example, and both wrap and orig are in the same namespace.

```
(defn orig []
    "OK")
(defn orig2 []
    "RES 2")

(defn wrap [f & args]
    (let [res (apply f args)]
        println "wrap" f args "=" res
        res))

(set! orig (wrap orig))
(set! orig2 (wrap orig2))
```

After evaluating last two forms orig and orig2 should be redefined to use wrapped versions.
Unfortunately I get the following error in REPL:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change/establish root binding of: orig with set (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `def/defn` again and it will change the definition of the function (technically it will write a new definition which uses the same name).

So you could just do:

```
(def orig (wrap orig))
(def orig2 (wrap orig2))
```

Also, if I understand your intention: `wrap` should be returning a function, not a result.

```
(defn wrap [f]
  (fn [& args]
    (let [res (apply f args)]
      (println "wrap" f args "=" res)
      res)))
```

If you look at the `memoize` standard function it works in precisely this way.

Comment: Thaks. Of course, I need to return a function. The problem I have now is changing function definition in another namespace. Just trying to redefine it throws an error "Can't create defs outside of current ns", but if i try to move orig into namepace x and do

(defn wrapns [ns f wrapf]
  (binding [*ns* (find-ns ns)]
    (def f (wrapf f))))

(wrapns 'x x/orig user/wrap)

It doesn't redefine original function?

Comment: Actually, I've just seen the documentation for [`alter-var-route`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/alter-var-root). It's actually perfect for what you're trying to do. ``(defmacro wrapns [var wrapfn] `(alter-var-route #'~var ~wrapfn))`` should work for you. Notice it's now a macro to avoid needing the `#'` on the function name wherever you call it. Example use: `(wrapns clojure.core/map wrap)`

Comment: Thanks, the macro is working nicely. I wander why if i try to change it to function (and remove quoting) it is giving an error when trying to wrap function orig/orig: java.lang.ClassCastException: orig$orig cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Var ?

Comment: The `#'` means to take the `var` that the symbol refers to rather than the value it's holding. (So you get the box rather than the value in the box). If you want it as a function you just have to call with `(wrapns #'clojure.core/map wrap)`, but I think it's cleaner without.

Comment: Eh.  `memoize`  doesn't do exactly that. Actually it does more: It returns a function that calls your function, but it caches the results for the calls, so that if it is called again with a given (set of) arg(s), it simply returns the same result, without actually calling your function.  Great for process-intensive functions, functions where a side-effect should only happen once, or where a call creates an instance of something and subsequent calls should return the same instance, not a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Clojure stores functions in `vars` to make this sort of code manipulation easier. you can just change the value of the var to reference the proper function.

if you have a list of potential caching functions then you can define them in their own namespace and have a bit of code that uses `def` to set the top level binding to point at the appropriate one.

```
(defn cache-all ...)
(defn cache-some ...)
(defn cache-none ...)

 (let [policy (get-current-policy)]
     (cond (= policy :all) (def cacher cache-all)
           (= policy :some) (def cacher cache-some)
           ...
           ))
```

if you need to actually define the function based on new input then `eval` is the idomatic approach.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I have tried to do something similar (I edited question) but it is not working the error says "... Can't change/establish root binding ..."

Comment: `set!` only works within the dynamic scope of a `binding` form, so it can only change a thread binding rather than the root binding.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the appropriate function as a variable to the code that does the work.

e.g.

```
user=> (defn strategy-1 [input] (+ input 3))
#'user/strategy-1
user=> (defn strategy-2 [input] (- input 3))
#'user/strategy-2
user=> (defn fun-user [fn input] (fn input))
#'user/fun-user
user=> (fun-user strategy-1 5)  
8
user=> (fun-user strategy-2 5)
2
```

This way you can decide up front which strategy to use, pick the appropriate function, and the pass it into the code that expects the caching function to do the right thing. The code can then just call the function that it receives as an argument.